# A weaker version of strongly graded algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, hopf-algebras

Let $A = \oplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} A_i$ be a graded algebra. We say that it is **strongly** graded if $A_i.A_j = A_{i+j}$, for all $i,j \in \mathbb{Z}$. Can there be existing a graded algebra such that 
$$
A_i.A_{-i} = A_0, ~~ \forall i \in \mathbb{Z},
$$
but which is yet not strongly graded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A_i \cdot A_{-i} = A_0$ then in particular we can write
$$
1 = \sum_k a_i^{(k)} \cdot a_{-i}^{(k)},
$$
where $a_l^{(k)} \in A_l$. Now taking any $a_{i+j} \in A_{i+j}$ and multiplying it by this equality, we obtain
$$
a_{i+j} = \sum_k a_i^{(k)} \cdot (a_{-i}^{(k)} \cdot a_{i+j}) \in A_i \cdot A_j.
$$